# Can INSERT and DELETE be added in one single executeBatch

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert

I  have hundreds of thousand of lines of text which need to be inserted and amang which there are hundred lines which should be deleted. The text file looks like below:

```
i 01 ppp
i 02 vvv
i 45 bbb
...
d 05
i 09 mmm
i 21 jjj
....
```

"i" indecates INSERT, "d" indecates deletes DELETE, the rest text of a lne is data which need be handled.

```
 insert into t1 (id, name)values(?, ?);
 delete from t1 where id = ?;
```

once a time I read 1000 lines , addBatch(), and executeBatch() for these "i" head lines, and those "d" head lines handled at last.
Is it possible that  i  add mixed insert and delete batch, then execute them?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 multi-row statements.

```
INSERT INTO t1 (id, name) VALUES (?, ?), (?, ?) ...;
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE id IN (?, ?, ...);
```

If you want atomic operation, lock table (statement depends on you DB)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database in question, you could try use the `merge` statement

Take a look at [Oracle's](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm) Merge statement for example

```
MERGE INTO bonuses D
  USING (SELECT employee_id, salary, department_id FROM employees
  WHERE department_id = 80) S
  ON (D.employee_id = S.employee_id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.bonus = D.bonus + S.salary*.01
    DELETE WHERE (S.salary > 8000)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (D.employee_id, D.bonus)
    VALUES (S.employee_id, S.salary*0.1)
    WHERE (S.salary <= 8000);
```

Comment: I see many samples that MERGE into one table from the other. I have only one table and a text file. i don't know if `merge` can do this.